# Bootstrap column arrangment

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

#### My HTML code :

```
<div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" id = '1stColoumn'>something</div>
    <div class="col-sm-8" id = '2ndColoumn'>something</div>
</div>
```

#### What it does :

- On large screens ,`1stColoumn` will be at the left and the `2ndColoumn` will be at the right.
- On small screens, `1stColoumn` will be at the top and the `2ndColoumn` will be at the bottom.

#### What I want it to do :

`2ndColoumn` should be at the top and the `1stColoumn` should be at the bottom.

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-push-3" id = '2ndColoumn'>something</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-pull-8" id = '1stColoumn'>something</div>
</div>
```

this will do.